# Bitwise expression to clear low byte of a constant

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am writing code that may run on architectures of different word size (32-bit, 64-bit, etc) and I want to clear the low byte of a value. There is a macro (MAX) that is set to the maximum value of a word. So, for example, on a 32-bit system MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF and on a 64-bit system MAX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for unsigned values. If I have a word-sized variable that may be signed or unsigned, how can I clear the low byte of the variable with a single expression (no branching)?

My first idea was:

```
value & ~( MAX - 0xFF )
```

but this does not appear to work for signed values. My other thought was:

```
value = value - (value & 0xFF)
```

which has the disadvantage that it requires a stack operation.

Comment: A low byte is cleared by ANDing with `~0xFF` on any (8-bit byte) architecture.

Comment: Note that the type of `MAX`'s expansion is independent of the types of other variables and values in expressions such as those you present.  Overall, though, it's not quite clear to me what problem you're trying to overcome.  I keep thinking there's some dimension that I haven't appreciated.

Comment: There is not such thing as a word-sized variable that may be signed or unsigned. You either made it signed, or you made it unsigned.

Comment: The question is all over the place. First you said that you are working with a *constant*. Then it is suddenly a *variable* that might be "signed or unsigned". So, what is it: a variable or a constant? You need to make up your mind. First of all, get "signed" out of the picture. Signed is not allowed. You are working with unsigned only. If you'll need signed, you'll convert the result later.

Answer (score 1):

To clear low byte, when not knowing the integer type width can result in incorrect code.  So code should be careful.

Consider the below where `value` is wider than `int/unsigned`.  `0xFF` is an `int` constant with the value 255. `~0xFF` is then that value with its bit inverted.  With common 2's complemented, that would be -256 with its upper bits set as FF...FF00.  -256 converted to a wider signed type retains its value and pattern FF...FF00.   -256 converted to a wider unsigned type becomes `Uxxx_MAX + 1 - 256`, agian with the bit pattern FF...FF00.  In both cases, the `&` will retain the uppers bits and clear the lower 8.

```
value_low_8bits_cleared = value & ~0xFF;
```

---

An alternative is to do all masking operation with *unsigned* math to avoid unexpected properties of `int` math  and `int` encodings.

The below has no concerns about sign extension, `int` overflow.  An optimizing compiler will certainly emit efficient code with a simply *and* mask.  Further, there is no need to code the correct matching *max* value corresponding to `value`.

```
value_low_8bits_cleared = (value | 0xFFu) ^ 0xFFu;
```

Comment: Code indeed should be careful in this area.  In service to that principle, it would be wise to avoid converting out-of-range values to signed integer types.

Answer (score 1):

here is the easy way to clear the low order 8 bits:

```
value &= ~0xFF;
```

Comment: Provided that `value`'s type is unsigned or that it is not wider than `int`.  Otherwise, you're in for a surprise.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The type of `~0xFF` is `int`, and its value is negative. So if `value`'s type is wider than `int`,  then `~0xFF` will be sign-extended, and this solution will work.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing code that may run on architectures of different word size
>   (32-bit, 64-bit, etc) and I want to clear the low byte of a value.
>
> There is a macro (MAX) that is set to the maximum value of a word. So,
>   for example, on a 32-bit system MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF and on a 64-bit
>   system MAX = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF for unsigned values.

Although C is designed so that implementations can take machine word size into account, the language itself has no inherent sense of machine words.  C cares instead about *types*, and that makes a difference.

Anyway, I take you exactly at your word that you arrange for the replacement text of macro `MAX` to be one of the two alternatives you give, depending on the architecture of the machine.  Note well that when that replacement text is interpreted as an integer constant, its type may vary between C implementations, and maybe even depending on compiler options.

> If I have a
>   word-sized variable that may be signed or unsigned, how can I clear
>   the low byte of the variable with a single expression (no branching)?

The only reason I see for needing a single expression that cannot take the actual type of `value` explicitly into account is that you want to use the expression in a macro itself.  In that case, you need to take great care around type conversions, especially when you have to account for signed types.  This makes your `MAX` macro uncomfortable to work with for your purpose.

I'm inclined to suggest a different approach:

```
(value | 0xFF) ^ 0xFF
```

The constant `0xFF` will be interpreted as a (signed) `int` with a positive value.  Provided that `value`'s type is not smaller than `int`, both appearances of `0xFF` will be converted to that type without change in value, whether that type is signed or unsigned.  Furthermore, the result of each operation and of the overall expression then has the same type as `value`, so no unexpected conversions occur.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
value & ~((intptr_t)0xFF)
```

Comment: In practice, this probably works fine most anywhere.  It matters, however, that it may involve a conversion of `value` to type `intptr_t`, and possibly other conversions depending on how the expression is used.

Comment: instead of `intptr_t` it may better to use `uintmax_t`

Answer (score 0):

First you want a mask that has all bits on, but those of the lower order byte

```
MAX ^ 0xFF
```

This converts `0xFF` to the same type as `MAX` and then does the exclusive or with that value. Because `MAX` has all low order bits `1` these then become `0` and the high order bits stay as they are, that is `1`.

Then you have to pull that mask over the value that interests you

```
value & ( MAX ^ 0xFF )
```

Comment: The description of `MAX ^ 0xFF` is incorrect. The low order bits are *inverted*. And in case `MAX` is not ending with `0xFF`, it is not going to work. What could work is `value & (value ^ 0xFF)`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., `MAX` is described in the question as the maximum value of the type. Thus it has all low order bits set to `1`.